# Carrierwave uploading file as non public

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave along with Google Cloud Storage. I've been using it for years.

On my last project images are uploaded but they are set as **non public** which makes my app throwing a 403 Error.

As in other projects I've set `config.fog_public = true` but it's not doing anything.

I know Google Cloud permission architecture has been updated recently. Am I missing something I should be aware of?

Carrierwave isn't throwing any error while uploading.

Comment: Have you considered just making the objects on Cloud Storage, or even the bucket itself, publicly accessible by following this documentation? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

Comment: Give public permission via shell works, it's just via Carrierwave that doesn't.

Comment: I ended up making the whole bucket public, but it's not a elegant solution. On my previous web apps it never happened which makes me think somewhere there's a misconfiguration. It's not on `carrierwave.rb` initializer nor in bucket permissions... don't know.